# How to prove this calculus inequation?

Tags: calculus

There are vectors $u,x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, we have that $\|u(t)\|\le u_{\mathrm{max}}$, and $\|x(t_0)\|\ge\|x(t)\|,t\ge t_0$, and there is a positive integer $T_0>0$. What kind of formula can we use to prove this inequation?

$\int_{t_0}^{t_0+T_0}|u^{\mathrm T}(t)[x(t_0)-x(t)]|dt\leq u_{\mathrm{max}}^2T_0\int_{t_0}^{t_0+T_0}|u^{\mathrm T}(t)x(t)|dt$

Comment: What do you mean by $u^T$? $u$ is not a scalar function.

Comment: $u^{\mathrm T}$ means the transpose of a vector, if a column vector is transposed then it becomes a row vector. $u$ is not a scalar indeed.

Comment: The doubt came up since you used the same symbol $T$ to denote the transpose and the constant $T$ appearing in your inequation.

Comment: $T$ and $\mathrm T$ are different symbols...

Answer (score 0):

The inequation
$$ \int_{t_0}^{t_0+T}|u^{\mathrm T}(t)[x(t_0)-x(t)]|dt\leq u_{\mathrm{max}}^2T\int_{t_0}^{t_0+T}|u^{\mathrm T}(t)x(t)|dt$$
is  false.

For example 
$$  \int_{t_0}^{t_0+T}|u^{\mathrm T}(t)[\lambda\,x(t_0)-\lambda\,x(t)]|dt  \nleq u_{\mathrm{max}}^2T\int_{t_0}^{t_0+T}|u^{\mathrm T}(t)x(t)|dt \quad \forall \lambda \in R$$

Comment: Why do you say this?

Comment: Could you explain it in detail?